# python3で<urlopen error unknown url type: https>の対処法

Tags: python

python3でurlを開こうとすると以下のエラーが出てしまいます。 
対処法を教えていただけませんでしょうか。環境はゲストOSのcentos7です。

■code

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from xml.etree.ElementTree import *
from urllib.request import urlopen
from urllib.parse import urlparse


url = ('https://hogehoge.com')
response = urlopen(url)
html = response.read()

print (html)
```

■error 
`<urlopen error unknown url type: https>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Pythonをソースコードからビルドしましたか？
2. PythonのSSLモジュールが利用出来ないのでは？（ `import ssl` を試してみてください）

https、つまりSSL通信ができないPython環境なのではないかと推測します。